# Deploy C# app with Entity framework+SQL Server Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, deployment, entity-framework-6

Sorry for that if it's repeating question but I could not find anything helpful.

I've developed a C# Winforms Application (Hostel Management System) using VS 2017 + MS SQL Server 2017
with EF 6.x. It is fully functional on my system (on which it's being developed). But now I wanna deploy it to my client. When I install it on any client machine and run, it works fine until any Database operation not happens. As soon as DB operation occurs, Application stops working and shows the error that it can't get connected to EF like this.
[image: Screenshot]

App.config is like shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DBModels.csdl|res://*/DBModels.ssdl|res://*/DBModels.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(localdb)\ProjectsV13;initial catalog=HMSDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

**Anyone here who can help me out to deploy my app successfully**

Comment: In the connection string, `provider connection string=&quot;data source=(localdb)\ProjectsV13;...` it's still pointing to your development environment. You need to change the part in between the two `&quot;`s to be something those machines can access.

Comment: <add name="DBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\testBD1.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

**i've also tried this one but not working.
can you help me how to change it if my app is going to be installed at i.e. C:\..\...\myapp**

Comment: Faisal_Mahmood. Are you using SQL Express or SQL Server full? attachDbFilename is sql express specific I believe. I don't have an answer though, other than your connection string is incorrect, but you know that. Your "data source" is pointing to your dev server, as @madreflection pointed out.
Take a look at this [MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aspnetue/2012/08/14/sql-server-connection-strings-for-asp_net-web-applications/) link, it may point you in the right direction.

Comment: I'm using sql server management studio 2017.

Comment: **Config mentioned in question is as it is produced by ADO.NET for sql server db (HMSDB)** which is using ProjectsV13 as server name

Connection string mentioned in comment is produced by ADO.Net for testDB1.mdf file which is standalone file that's why it shows attachdbFilename

both work fine at dev pc but not at client pc

**i'm asking for what change should be done to these strings so that it can run on client machine**